# Finding identical lines over multiple files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know there is a lot of similar questions, but none of them seem to work.

Let me begin:

I have two files, one called `client-gen.txt`, and another called `server-gen.txt`. The files contain randomly generated SHA1 strings, for example:

```
902ba3cda1883801594b6e1b452790cc53948fda
356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
c1dfd96eea8cc2b62785275bca38ac261256e278
1b6453892473a467d07372d45eb05abc2031647a
77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb
```

Now, the question is, if I have the other file, looking like this:

```
77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb
da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0
356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
1b6453892473a467d07372d45eb05abc2031647a
356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
ac3478d69a3c81fa62e60f5c3696165a4e5e6ac4
da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0
356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
1b6453892473a467d07372d45eb05abc2031647a
da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0
```

How can I compare these files, and just print in this case:

```
77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb
1b6453892473a467d07372d45eb05abc2031647a
1b6453892473a467d07372d45eb05abc2031647a
```

The order is not important.

FYI, I have already tried using `set()` and other methods. None of them seem to work.

If you can help, I really appreciate it

Comment: Add each line to dictionary as a key and value as a counter. If value is already in dictionary then increment counter.

Comment: @ThePavolC Sorry, it's not a matter of counting them, its a matter of finding them

Comment: why is `356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab` not printed twice or at all for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your expected output is incorrect as you don't include  `'356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab'` which appears in both and furthermore appears twice in your second file, if you want elements that appear in both files use set.intersection:

```
with open("a.txt") as a, open("b.txt") as b:
    st = set(map(str.rstrip,a))
    print("\n".join(st.intersection(map(str.rstrip,b))))


356a192b7913b04c54574d18c28d46e6395428ab
1b6453892473a467d07372d45eb05abc2031647a
77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb
```

Comment: Sorry for the inactivity, been busy, just checked this, and implemented it into my code, this works exceedingly well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and then only print the items with a value of 2. Since an open file is iterable (i.e. you can iterate over the lines when you use a for loop), you can call `Counter` directly on the open files:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('file1') as file1, open('file2') as file2:
    ids = Counter(file1)
    ids.update(file2)
for key, value in ids.items():
    if value > 1:
        print(key)
```

This method will include the trailing newlines.  It's likely that this isn't what you want; if that is the case, you'll have to iterate over the files explicitly and remove the whitespace explicitly:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('file1') as file1, open('file2') as file2:
    ids = Counter()
    for line in file1:
        ids.update([line.strip()])
    for line in file2:
        ids.update([line.strip()])

for key, value in ids.items():
    if value > 1:
        print(key)
```

Comment: Okay, so then how would I output the matches to the user?

Comment: Sorry, I was dumb and misread your question.  I have updated my answer to do what you wanted, though.

Comment: @RPiPasswordGen Oops, changed it to `ids.update(file2)`.

Comment: Right, I guess that works, but how on earth am i meant to return the original text?

Comment: @RPiPasswordGen I keep being the worst.  Just change printing the value to print the key.

Answer (score 1):

Sort both files in in alphabetic order. Then in a single merge-like pass, you will find all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
cl = [l.strip() for l in open("client-gen.txt")]
sl = [l.strip() for l in open("server-gen.txt")]
common = filter(lambda l: l in sl, cl)
```